# Reducer Action Not Dynamically Updating

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a basic CRUD app using React/Redux with a Rails API, and when I submit a car on my car-form, I get an error message - but refreshing the browser shows the car.

The error says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` on line 20 of my Cars.js file:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import CarCard from '../components/CarCard';
import CarForm from './CarForm';
import './Cars.css';
import { getCars } from '../actions/cars';


class Cars extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCars()
}

render() {
    return (
    <div className="CarsContainer">
        <h3>Cars Component</h3> 
        {this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}
        <CarForm />
    </div>
    );
}
```

}

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return ({
        cars: state.cars
    })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCars })(Cars);
```

Here's my `createCar` action creator:

```
const addCar = car => {
return {
    type: 'CREATE_CAR_SUCCESS',
    car
}}
```

And my `createCar` async action:

```
export const createCar = car => {
return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/cars`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ car: car })
    })
    .then(response => {
      try {
        return response.json()
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
    .then(cars => {
        dispatch(addCar([car]));
        dispatch(resetCarForm())
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error + 'createCar POST failed'))
}}
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, seeing as the app reflects my changes after I reload. Ultimately I'm trying to show that information without having to refresh the page.

Comment: What is the output of cars if you do console.log(this.props.cars)

Comment: post the reducer code and the resetCarForm function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when your component mounts, it doesn’t have the cars array and instead it has an undefined value.
This happens because `getCars()` is asynchronous.

**Solution 1:** add a defaultProp to the component:

```
Component.defaultProps = {
cars: { cars: [] }
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Add a cars key to the reducer’s `initialState`

```
initialState: { cars:{ cars:[] } }
```

Comment: Is adding an `initialState` different than the `export default (state = {cars: []}, action)...` that I currently have?

Comment: Yes. Its only different because {cars: []} isn’t the same as {cars: {cars: []}}. I guess your problem is that you are getting your array nested in your redux store. Thats why you are doing this.props.cars.cars.map(...) at Cars component. To verify this try a console.log at the response in your Promise’s .the

Comment: Thanks, I apologize but where specifically would I be adding that code?

Comment: If you go for Solution 1 -> do it at Cars component, so before exporting it you write: Cars.defaultProps ={...}.If you go for Solution 2 you can do it at your reducer: export default (state={cars: {cars:[]}},action)

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering before your async action puts the values in the state.  Try returning `null` from render if your state is not set yet:

```
render() {
    if(!this.props.cars.cars){
      return null;
    }
    return (
    <div className="CarsContainer">
        <h3>Cars Component</h3> 
        {this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}
        <CarForm />
    </div>
    );
}
```

In other words, if your state does not have a list of things to render return null - I *think* the above if will work, but you might want to `console.log("Cars in render", this.props.cars)` to see what you are getting.

The better option, IMO, is to set your initial state so that `this.props.cars` is `[]` and then you don't have to return null and have a special case in your `render` method.  I would need to see your reducer to suggest how to do that, but if you make it have a sensible default/initial state you should be able to easily do this.

Comment: console.logging it returns an empty cars array, so I need to find a way to get the cars array before this all gets loaded

Answer (score 1):

You are doing action call getCars in componentDidMount and this lifecycle method gets called after first render so on Initial render this.props.cars will be undefined

If you are getting this.props.cars like

```
   {
       “cars”: [....]
    }
```

Then you need to do conditional check before accessing cars object

Change

```
       {this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}
```

To

```
         {this.props.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}
```

Comment: I swapped out the line, but cars is still returning as undefined. Do I need to restart my server or anything?

Comment: @victor.ja I added that, and this time it submits, and only renders the form again (with the same information). Submit > adds to database but doesn't show any cars > keeps the info in the form. Upon refresh I see the submitted car

Comment: componentDidMount only triggers once, when the component is mounted. You need to call getCars() again at componentDidUpdate() to trigger a re-fetch of cars [getCars]

Comment: @victor.ja Worked! Thank you so much for your help.